# CSRF token issue when upgrading Django to version 4.*

Tags: python, django, django-4.0

I was using the Django version 3, but then upgraded it to Django version 4(**django==4.0.6**).

After logging to admin panel of Django project, it said that *CSRF* token is invalid.
I found [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0) in Django documentation and tried to put such variable in `settings.py`:

```py
ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['https://*', 'http://*']
```

But it didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ALLOWED_ORIGINS  has nothing to do with CSRF Token. Try to migrate again if data isn't important.

Comment: What's the output of `./manage.py check` ?

Comment: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ALLOWED_ORIGINS` is not related to `CSRF` token. To fix problems related to your issue, you must specify the following setting for the project in production mode to `settings.py` module:

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
        'https://subdomain.example.com',
        'https://*.blob.com',
        ...
    ]
```

For reading more information related to this topic you can read [CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins).